# How to make userprofile viewing-editing in django similar to the facebook way?

Tags: ajax, django, facebook, django-forms, profile

I'm making a site in django which has profiles for users and companies with text fields, photos, choices, etc., and I want them to look the same while viewing or editing them (in case of the owner of the profile). Basically the user must click somewhere and all the information  becomes editable, without having to go into other "profile editing" page.

The only way of doing this that I can think of is by making to different pages, one for only "viewing" the data, and other for editing it, and try to make them look the same anyhow..

I wonder, if there is an elegant and simple way of integrating this two functionalities in django?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about manipulating the DOM without page loads. You're going to use AJAX to retrieve your form. I would recommend using [Tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to create REST endpoints. Then you'll need to do AJAX calls to get your form. I would recommend using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

If you would prefer something simplier. You could always user a hidden form field and then manipulate the DOM with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: This is very useful, although I'm looking for some kind of "special" form or something that will have this two modes: a read-only and a write one, and easily switch between those two in case you are just viewing the profile or want to change something in it.  Hope it makes some sense. Thanks @drewman

Comment: I ended up using both methods, a toggle button that shows/hide the form data and the data to display, and Tastypie for the updating proccess.